CFI Expiration date
My CFI Certificate Issue date was 7 Dec 2022. Do the new rules for CFI renewal mean that my I can renew my certificate by taking, (and passing)  an online FIRC course at any time from now until 31 March 2025 ?

Yes. The updated text of 14 CFR 61.199(a)(1) reads:

If 3 calendar months or less have passed since the last month of the flight
instructor’s recent experience period, the flight instructor may successfully complete an
approved flight instructor refresher course consisting of ground training or flight training,
or a combination of both, or satisfy one of the requirements specified in paragraph (a)(2)
of this section.

The updated text of 14 CFR 61.197(e) reads:

A person who holds an unexpired flight instructor certificate issued before
December 1, 2024, may renew that certificate by establishing recent experience in
accordance with paragraph (b) of this section prior to the month of expiration on that
person’s flight instructor certificate. Except as provided in § 61.40, if that person fails to
establish recent experience prior to the expiration of that person’s flight instructor
certificate, that person may not exercise flight instructor privileges until those privileges
are reinstated in accordance with § 61.199.

Between the expiration date and when it is reinstated you cannot exercise the privileges of the certificate.
It might be wise to check with your local FSDO before committing to letting it expire, just in case they have a different interpretation!
